# Retrieving an array from chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to use `chrome.storage` to store an array which it receives from *popup.js*.

Here's my *background.js*:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        //obtains a unique array with all the urls the user entered to save
        var tabs = request.url; // receives array
        chrome.storage.local.set({tabs: tabs}, function () {});
    }
);
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function (tabs) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("tabs", function () {
        storedInputs = tabs.tabs.newValue.concat(tabs.tabs.oldValue)
                           .filter(function (item, index, inputArray) { //removes duplicates
            return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
        });;
        console.log(storedInputs);
    });
});
```

When I looked at the contents of the storage there are two objects called and `oldValue` and a `newValue`. The `oldValue` contains the array with terms prior to opening up the extension. The `newValue` contains newly entered terms. For some reason. The first time I open the popup and pass values, it contains all the data. The next time, only data entered from that particular instance is present.

Here's a sample output:
[image: sample output]

Comment: Why are you using message passing instead of just storing the data in your *popup.js*? Your `chrome.storage.local.get` appears completely unused; you don't even pass an argument to your callback.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].